# Java Multi-Threading. Можно ли завершать поток и получать значение по условию, а в противном случае повторять вызов?

Tags: java, spring, многопоточность, spring-boot

Название может сбить с толку, потому что вопрос не тривиальный и я не могу кратко его описать.

Представим есть класс имитирующий ответ от микросервиса:

```
public class MicroserviceCallEmulator implements CallEmulator {

    private static final List<String> VALUES = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");

    @Override
    public String doCall() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

        return VALUES.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3));
    }
}
```

В нём есть метод `doCall()`, который имитирует задержку а потом возвращает одно из значений списка `VALUES`. И есть класс использующий этот имитатор:

```
public class MicroserviceCallProvoker implements CallProvoker {

    private final CallEmulator callEmulator;

    public MicroserviceCallProvoker(CallEmulator callEmulator) {
        this.callEmulator = callEmulator;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        callEmulator.doCall();
    }
}
```

В методе `doSomething()` нужно реализовать следующую логику:

1. Вызов `doCall()` должен быть асинхронным. То есть `doSomething()` должен просто отправлять запрос и ничего не ждать и не возвращать.
2. Значения `A` и `B` ответе от `doCall()` являются не подходящими. Вызовы нужно продолжать асинхронно до тех пор, пока от `doCall()` не вернёться `C`
3. Вызовы `doCall()` после непдоходящего ответа необходимо повторно посылать НЕ сразу же, а по истечению 10 секунд
4. Есть предел по времени. Повторные вызовы `doCall()` должны быть ограничены по времени. К примеру, `doCall()` может 1000 раз вернуть строку `A`и это займёт 1000 секунд. Такое поведение не подходит. Мы должны пытаться вызывать его в течении 400 секунд и потом (даже если не получили заветную строку `C`) прекращать выполнение асинхронной задачи.

Не подумайте, я не прошу Вас решать какую-то задачу. Это - реальная проблема с которой я столкнулся и я не могу понять какими средствами `Java` можно реализовать столь сложную цепь, если это вообще возможно. Асинхронно пульнуть задачу не трудно, но как это повторять до подходящего условия и ограничить такое повторение по времени?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала всю логику повтороных попыток реализовываем в отдельной функции:

```
void doCallWithRetry() {
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(400, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
         String result = callEmulator.doCall();
         if (result.equal("C")) {
            break;
         }
         TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    }    
}
```

И теперь запускаем `doCallWithRetry` в отдельном потоке из `doSomething` (в примере использую ExecutorService, но можно любой другой способ запуска в отдельном потоке):

```
void doSomething() {
   executorService.execute(this::doCallWithRetry);
}
```

Comment: А есть какие-то более высокоуровневые API, чтобы так делать? Может быть что-то из пакета `Spring`, `Circuit Breaker` или `java.util.concurrent`? Или это слишком специфичная задача, чтобы использовать какое-то высокоуровневые API? Приведу пример с `org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler#schedule(java.lang.Runnable, java.time.Instant)`. В данном методе можно указать действие (Runnable) и время через которое это действие стоит воспроизвести. Быть может есть что-то подобное и для такой задачи?